# AWS SES verified email address send a test mail issue

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Hello guys sorry I am new in AWS,

I am having trouble with sending email address from AWS.

**Here is my configuration detail :**

1) I have successfully verified my email addresses and domain as well.

[image]

2) same I have add IAM user as well from with following policy

{ "Statement": [{
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":"ses:SendRawEmail",
        "Resource":"*"
}]}

3) You can see add mail address are verified

[image: You can see add mail address are verified]

But thought I do not nkow why I get follwing error once I tried to send mail.

[image]

I received following error

"Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: ronak.amlani@gmail.com (Request ID: a84ef5d9-1778-11e6-aa63-c3cc30c338dc)"

Please please help me to come out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...
Am I rite, you are trying to send to 'Test'? So this `address` is not valid - true.

Comment: try to add @domain.tld :)

Comment: Yes, even does not work with node.js as well. 

What is TLD, I have verified domain by given add record ?

Thank you so much for quick reply..

Comment: Your screenshot says that you have in 'TO' field something which is not an email address.
It must be in form : test@somedomain.com

Comment: Thank you so much for report and sorry for my silly mistake, yes after change stil lI got same error, I have changed in my question.

Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify "To" addresses while sending emails in Sandbox mode.

Comment: Quite correct! However, I think the OP has already verified the TO address, as per the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your are in under sandbox environment quota so your unable to send emails if you put request to AWS for increasing sending quota then you have to send un-verified emails also.